# Produce .jar -> including .txt file is not found

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, buildpath

In my project i write into and read from a project.txt file. This project.txt file is first reading in by programm start. 
All works perfectly, but if i export my project as a .jar file and try to execute this .jar file, then my programm says, that he could not find the project.txt (i created this error-message).

The path of project.txt is "./res/project.txt". The res-folder is included in the build-path of this project. I'm using Eclipse.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The code matters. Post the code. And the stack trace of the exception. But be aware that you can't write to a file inside a jar file.

Comment: It may be because you are treating it as File, post relevant code and exception for more detail

Comment: @ JB Nizet: That i could not write to a file inside a jar file is new for me! That could be the mistake. But i can't tell you the exception, because i run this as a .jar file without eclipse. But that i could not write to a file inside a jar file makes my whole programm actually useless and i need to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: @user3146246: open a command line, and type `java -jar theJarFile.jar`. That will launch the program and you'll be able to see the stack traces in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO READ

Two possible causes:

1. you are trying to access the project.txt through java.io  and not as resource (please post the code)
2. you access through ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/project.txt"); but the file was not exported into the jar (please post the code)

in othe words: the "./res/project.txt" is near the eclipse project path but outside the scope of the jar.

TO WRITE

Finally the writing into the jar file is absolutly not Java compliant, it should work in some cases such as ear or war and not jar.